# jquery does closest() find the prev() first then parent() or just parent()

Tags: jquery

Because I have never known the answer to this question and I am needing to know for some code of mine I was curious about how `closest()` actually works in jquery.

I know that (according to their [docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)) that

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

When they say "traversing up" does this mean it will go up the `parent()` or does it actually go to the `prev()` first and so on till it finds the `parent()` and then moves on up as such.

Basically I need to know when it traverses up does it go to prev first then parent or does it just go up to the parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest first checks to see if the element, itself, matches the selector.  If so it will return itself.  After that, it goes up the parent tree checking each parent to see if it matches the selector, stopping as soon as it finds the first match.

Comment: So then it does not check the `prev()` first? Just parents?

Comment: `prev()` is a sideways operation.  `closest()` is an upwards operation.